# Chrome.storage wont store Array correctly

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

im working on a chrome extension and have problems with the chrome.storage api. I want to save a Array to the storage, the array gets stored, but not the values of the array. So array[x] is always 'null'. Code looks like this:

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;
bookmarks = new Array();

var newButton = document.createElement('input');
//... Button properys are getting set
bookmarks[bookmarks.length] = newButton; //tried it also with .push()
var obj = {};
obj['bookmarks'] = bookmarks;
storage.set(obj, function(){ console.log('bookmark saved'); });
```

After restarting the extension and getting the storage via:

```
storage.get(null, function(result){
    console.log('Storage: ', result);
    });
```

the log looks like this:

```
Storage:  
Object
bookmarks: Array[1]
0: null
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

Any suggestions whats going wrong and why the array isnt stored correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: if you print the newButton variable, what do you get ?

Comment: if i log the Button i get:<input type="button" value="blahblahbla">

Comment: if you fix the index, like this - bookmarks[0] = newButton; does it still store null ?

Comment: still null in the storage. bookmarks[0] is newButton

Comment: if you store newButton in the storage object outside the bookmarks array, is it still null ? As far as I can see, there are no errors in the code visible to me.

Comment: If i only store the Button, there is nothing in the storage, not even a null-reference :(

Comment: The get(null, callback) might be the problem. Try with a non-null reference. ex. storage.get('bookmarks', callback), otherwise im out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store an object in `Chrome.storage`, the object must be serializable. You can test whether or not an object is serializable, by attempting to `JSON.stringify()` it. If you try the following in your console:

```
JSON.stringify(document.createElement('input'));
```

You will see an error gets thrown - `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`. Which means the object cannot be serialized, as it contains references to self.

Seeing as DOM elements cannot be serialized, and thus cannot be stored, a solution would be to create a new object, add the desired button properties to it, and store that instead:

```
bookmarks = new Array();
var newButton = document.createElement('input');
//... Button properties are getting set
var data = {
    prop: newButton.prop
};
bookmarks.push(data);
storage.set({ bookmarks: bookmarks });
```

Comment: Just a heads-up: Unlike `localStorage`, `chrome.storage` can store and retrieve JSON objects directly. There is no need for `JSON.stringify/parse`.

Comment: thx, i will try this tomorrow...too tired now. will ofc give you feedback

Comment: The actual problem is not that hes storing an object instead of string, but that such object needs to be serializable. This answer should be corrected to avoid confusion about chrome.storage vs localStorage

Comment: @levi the answer still says "When storing an object in Chrome.storage, the object must first be serialized into a string" but that is not correct. chrome.storage does allow you to store the object without having to serialize it, it just needs to be serializable. see http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

Answer (score 1):

The newButton object is too complex to store. Instead you should store a primitive value. E.g. if you run the following the expected `{bookmarks:[{foo:"bar"}]}` can be retrieved from storage.local.

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;
bookmarks = new Array();

bookmarks[bookmarks.length] = {foo:"bar"};
var obj = {};
obj['bookmarks'] = bookmarks;
storage.set(obj, function(){ console.log('bookmark saved'); });
```